# Gitlab CI/CD: default value for environment variables

Tags: gitlab-ci

I would like to write a pipeline and include some default values that could be overridden by the user in the project CI/CD settings.

Could I do something like the .gitlab-ci.yml bellow? It's not clear in the documentation...

```
variables:
  VAR: $VAR || "default"
```

Or the user set tis value in the settings, or use the default value.

regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables defined in .gitlab-ci.yml are overwritten by variables defined on the project level:

```yaml
try-job:
  image: ubuntu:20.04
  variables:
    VAR1: 'var 1 set in gitlab-ci.yml'
    VAR2: 'var 2 set in gitlab-ci.yml'
  script:
    - echo $VAR1;
    - echo $VAR2;
```

When setting VAR2 variable manually during Pipeline trigger to `var 2 set in project cicd variable`

[image]

https://gitlab.com/mouson-gitlab-playground/gitlab-ci-parallel-test01/-/jobs/1821982396

---

The order of precedence for variables is (from highest to lowest):

1. Trigger variables, scheduled pipeline variables, and manual pipeline run variables.
2. Project variables.
3. Group variables.
4. Instance variables.
5. Inherited variables.
6. Variables defined in jobs in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
7. Variables defined outside of jobs (globally) in the .gitlab-ci.yml file.
8. Deployment variables.
9. Predefined variables.

ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/index.html#cicd-variable-precedence

Comment: thanks a lot. I read this list on the docs, but I was not sure. thanks.